# How to find span element in selenium webdriver which is not having any other attributes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a report which is completely of HTML based. I'm trying to automate and using selenium webdriver for finding the elements. In one of the part, below is the HTML format

```
<tbody>  
<tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid #D1D1D1; background-color:#F4F4F4; color: #707070;padding :2px;">
    <table style="width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 15px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;" role="presentation"> 
          <tbody><tr>
  <!--Action Date -->
            <td></td>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="right">
                <span style="font-size: 12px;">12/7/20 10:21 AM</span>
            </td>
  </tr>
         <tr>
        <!-- Name and status column -->
            <td style="" width="25" valign="top" align="center">
              <img src="images/qual_checkmark_24.png" alt="">
             </td>
            <td width="535">
                <span>First line of <strong>TEXT</strong></span>
             </td>
        </tr>
             
        </tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid #D1D1D1; background-color:#F4F4F4; color: #707070;padding :2px;">
    <table style="width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 15px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;" role="presentation"> 
        
          <tbody><tr>
  <!--Action Date -->
            <td></td>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="right">
                <span style="font-size: 12px;">12/7/20 10:18 AM</span>
            </td>
  </tr>
         <tr>
        <!-- Name and status column -->
            <td style="" width="25" valign="top" align="center">
              <img src="images/qual_arrowupcircleblue_24.png" alt="">
             </td>
            <td width="535">
                <span>Second line of<strong>TEXT</strong></span>
             </td>
        </tr>     
        </tbody>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I wanted to find the text in span tag (eg: first line of text, second line of text ) where i don't have any other attributes. I tried various other way of finding it via xpath, cssSelector and nothing works. Could someone help?

Comment: *I tried various other way....*. Show at least some of them

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this XPath to *select `span` nodes without attributes*:

```
//span[not(@*)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//tbody/tr[2]/td/span
```

you can use the parent as reference, in the html you provided the span is under the tr which is second element of tbody.

`//tbody/tr[2]` , will find all elements which are second child of tbody , and then direct child td/span

Comment: @this select only second td , as only this has span as child , and it's direct child also . So only that will be selected not first td

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both answers would be probably best:

```
//tbody/tr/td/span[not(@*)]
```

It's still flexible and less error-prone at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sets of `<span>` tags. One that holds the datetime e.g. *12/7/20 10:18 AM* and the other that holds the text e.g *TEXT*.

To print the *list* of `<span>` tag texts you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  List<String> myTexts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//tbody//tr/td/table/tbody//tr//td/span[./strong]"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  System.out.println(myTexts);
  ```